# Javascript Overwriting Same Named Functions Despite Conditionals In Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In my javascript file I am using `var screenheight = window.screen.height`

I am using this height measurement to determine whether to use one set of functions or an almost identical set of functions. All of the functions have the exact same names, but if someone's screen height is above a certain threshold, they will get one set rather than the other.

This works perfectly fine in Firefox, but in Chrome it uses the latter set of functions no matter what.

Another odd thing about this behavior is that before I have the sets of functions in their conditionals, I have a conditional that properly sets the style of some elements based on that screen height call.

I don't know why it's doing this. It looks similar to this oversimplification below.

```
var screenheight = window.screen.height;
window.onload = init;

function init() {
if(screenheight > 800 && screenheight <= 1100) {
document.getElementById("someid").style.height = 700px;
}
}

if(screenheight > 700 && screenheight <= 800) {
function functionone() {
document.getElementById("someotherid").style.height = 500px;
}
} else if(screenheight > 800 && screenheight <= 1000) {
function functionone() {
document.getElementById("someotherid").style.height = 600px;
}
}
```

This works perfectly fine in Firefox, but Chrome prefers the second version of `functionone()`

EDIT: I cleaned up the fake code a bit for clarity. Missing brackets and malformed conditionals.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are missing some closing brackets in your functions?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `screenheight > 800 && screenheight <= 1100` instead of `screenheight > 800 && <= 1100` ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript won't use block scope unless you use the 'let' keyword.

It looks like there are some typos that would stop chrome from running this.

- missing quotes on px values
- missing values before <=
- unclosed functions,
- uncalled functions
- unclosed else if statement

This is untested but give it a try to fix up the syntax.

```
var screenheight = window.screen.height;
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  if(screenheight > 800 && screenheight <= 1100) {
    document.getElementById("someid").style.height = '700px';
  }
}

if(screenheight > 700 && screenheight <= 800) {
  (function functionone () {
    document.getElementById("someotherid").style.height = '500px';
  })();
} else if(screenheight > 800 && screenheight <= 1000) {
  (function functionone() {
    document.getElementById("someotherid").style.height = '600px';
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *JavaScript does not have block-level scope (variables scoped to surrounding curly brackets); instead, JavaScript has function-level scope. Variables declared within a function are local variables and are only accessible within that function or by functions inside that function.*[Ref](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/)

In JavaScript, all the global functions are `child` of `window` object.

In this example, `function functionone()` which is declared later in the code will always override the earlier function.

It will be much like this:

```js
var obj = {
  a: 10
};
obj.a = 20;
alert(obj.a);
```

You can try this approach:

```js
var screenheight = window.screen.height;
//screenheight = 900;
var functionone = (function() {
  if (screenheight > 700 && screenheight <= 800) {
    return function() {
      document.getElementById("someotherid").style.height = '500px';
    }
  } else if (screenheight > 800 && screenheight <= 1000) {
    return function() {
      document.getElementById("someotherid").style.height = '600px';
    }
  }
})();
console.log(functionone);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div id="someotherid"></div>
```

**Edit:** You have syntax errors, missing quotes and missing variable in conditions in your code as highlighted by [curtwphillips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846930/curtwphillips)